# Why can't I call function on companion object?

Tags: scala

In the code below, why can't I call the sum function when I create an instance of fpinscala.datastructures.List? I.e. in the SBT console I do the following:

```
scala> :paste  -raw exercises/src/main/scala/fpinscala/datastructures/List.scala
scala> val list = fpinscala.datastructures.List(2,3)
scala> list.sum(fpinscala.datastructures.List(2,3))
```

I guess my problem is I don't really understand the companion object - although my understanding was that it just defined functions on the type I have created which I could then call?

```
package fpinscala.datastructures                                                                                        

sealed trait List[+A] // `List` data type, parameterized on a type, `A`                                                 
case object Nil extends List[Nothing] // A `List` data constructor representing the empty list                          
/* Another data constructor, representing nonempty lists. Note that `tail` is another `List[A]`,                        
which may be `Nil` or another `Cons`.                                                                                   
 */                                                                                                                     
case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]                                                             

object List { // `List` companion object. Contains functions for creating and working with lists.                       
  def sum(ints: List[Int]): Int = ints match { // A function that uses pattern matching to add up a list of integers    
    case Nil => 0 // The sum of the empty list is 0.                                                                    
    case Cons(x,xs) => x + sum(xs) // The sum of a list starting with `x` is `x` plus the sum of the rest of the list.  
  }                                                                                                                     

  def product(ds: List[Double]): Double = ds match {                                                                    
    case Nil => 1.0                                                                                                     
    case Cons(0.0, _) => 0.0                                                                                            
    case Cons(x,xs) => x * product(xs)                                                                                  
  }                                                                                                                     

  def apply[A](as: A*): List[A] = // Variadic function syntax                                                           
    if (as.isEmpty) Nil                                                                                                 
    else Cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*)) 
}
```

EDIT: Maybe a better question is, how would I implement the following:

```
 scala> val list = fpinscala.datastructures.List(2,3)
 scala> list.sum (should return 5)
```

Comment: Companion object is not so important at scala syntax level. It shares with accompanied non-case class merely nothing except implicit values. But when it comes to bytecode - methods of companion object becomes also static methods. So it becomes super important when you dealing with: Java coop, case classes or other auto-generated things like [`Lenses`](https://github.com/julien-truffaut/Monocle#lens-creation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that this line:

```
val list = fpinscala.datastructures.List(2,3)
```

is the same as the following:

```
val list = fpinscala.datastructures.List.apply(2,3)
```

In other words, you are calling the method `apply` in the `List` object. The return type of the `apply` method is the **trait** `List`, so the type of the val `list` is the trait `List`.

This means that when you call `list.sum`, you're trying to call the `sum` method of the **trait** `List`. But your trait `List` does not have a `sum` method, so it fails.

You have put the `sum` method in the companion object of trait `List` - you should put it in the trait instead (removing the parameter; or call the `sum` in the `List` object, passing `list` as the argument, as Seth Tisue noted in his comment).

A trait or class does not automatically have all the methods of its companion object.

Answer (score 0):

Answering question about how to implement list.sum: you should define method in your List trait. Take a look at scala.collection.TraversableOnce 'sum' implementation:

```
def sum[B >: A](implicit num: Numeric[B]): B = foldLeft(num.zero)(num.plus)
```

So far List has arbitrary type, implicit instance of Numeric monoid is required - it gives zero value and operation (plus in the case of sum)